# Writing concurrently with channels

Tags: go, concurrency, channel

I wrote a short script to write a file concurrently.
One goroutine is supposed to write strings to a file while the others are supposed to send the messages through a channel to it.
However, for some really strange reason the file is created but no message is added to it through the channel.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "sync"
)

var wg sync.WaitGroup
var output = make(chan string)

func concurrent(n uint64) {
    output <- fmt.Sprint(n)
    defer wg.Done()
}

func printOutput() {
    f, err :=  os.OpenFile("output.txt", os.O_CREATE|os.O_RDWR|os.O_APPEND, 0666);
    if err != nil {
            panic(err)
    }
    defer f.Close()

    for msg := range output {
            f.WriteString(msg+"\n")
    }
}

func main() {
    wg.Add(2)
    go concurrent(1)
    go concurrent(2)
    wg.Wait()
    close(output)
    printOutput()
}
```

The `printOutput()` goroutine is executed completely, if I tried to write something after the for loop it would actually get into the file. So this leads me to think that range output might be null

Comment: @Snowman Should be much better now, https://play.golang.org/p/Cx6mcUHiSU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the reason why you get a null `output` is because *channels* are `blocking` for both send/receive.

According to your flow, the code snippet below will never reach `wg.Done()`, as sending channel is expecting a receiving end to pull the data out. This is a typical deadlock example.

```
func concurrent(n uint64) {
    output <- fmt.Sprint(n) // go routine is blocked until data in channel is fetched.
    defer wg.Done()
}
```

Let's examine the main func:

```
func main() {
    wg.Add(2)
    go concurrent(1)  
    go concurrent(2)
    wg.Wait()       // the main thread will be waiting indefinitely here.
    close(output)   
    printOutput()
}
```

---

Comment: @Juanvulcano you close the channel after `wg.Wait()` anyway. `wg.Done()` isn't reached because `output <- fmt.Sprint(n)` blocks waiting for `printOutput()` to take the value off. And you never get to `printOutput()` because it's also after `wg.Wait()` . Thus you wait permanently at `wg.Done()`

Answer (score 3):

You need to have something taking from the output channel as it is blocking until something removes what you put on it.

Not the only/best way to do it but: I moved `printOutput()` to above the other funcs and run it as a go routine and it prevents the deadlock.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "sync"
)

var wg sync.WaitGroup
var output = make(chan string)

func concurrent(n uint64) {
    output <- fmt.Sprint(n)
    defer wg.Done()
}

func printOutput() {
    f, err := os.OpenFile("output.txt", os.O_CREATE|os.O_RDWR|os.O_APPEND, 0666)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer f.Close()

    for msg := range output {
        f.WriteString(msg + "\n")
    }
}

func main() {
    go printOutput()
    wg.Add(2)
    go concurrent(1)
    go concurrent(2)
    wg.Wait()
    close(output)
}
```

Comment: not correct. Your close might ends the program before pintOuput finishes.

Answer (score 1):

My take on the problem:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "sync"
)

var wg sync.WaitGroup
var output = make(chan string)
var donePrinting = make(chan struct{})

func concurrent(n uint) {
    defer wg.Done() // It only makes sense to defer
     // wg.Done() before you do something.
     // (like sending a string to the output channel)
    output <- fmt.Sprint(n)
}

func printOutput() {
    f, err := os.OpenFile("output.txt", os.O_CREATE|os.O_RDWR|os.O_APPEND, 0666)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer f.Close()

    for msg := range output {
        f.WriteString(msg + "\n")
    }
    donePrinting <- struct{}{}
}

func main() {
    wg.Add(2)
    go printOutput()
    go concurrent(1)
    go concurrent(2)
    wg.Wait()
    close(output)
    <-donePrinting
}
```

Each `concurrent` function will deduct from the wait-group.

After the two `concurrent` goroutines finish, the `wg.Wait()` will unblock, and the next instruction (`close(output)`) will be executed. You have to wait for the two goroutines to finish before closing the channel. If, instead, you try the following:

```
go printOutput()
go concurrent(1)
go concurrent(2)
close(output)
wg.Wait()
```

you could end up with the `close(output)` instruction executing before any one of the `concurrent` goroutines concludes. If the channel closes before the concurrent goroutines run, they will crash at runtime, (while trying to write to a closed channel).

If, then, you don’t wait up for the `printOutput()` goroutine to finish, you could actually quit `main()` before `printOutput()` has gotten the chance to finish writing to its file.

Because I want to wait for the `printOutput()` goroutine to finish before I quit the program, I also created a separate channel just to signal that `printOutput()` is done.

The `<-donePrinting` instruction blocks until `main` receives something over the `donePrinting` channel.
Once `main` receives anything (even the empty structure that `printOutput()` sends), it will unblock and run to conclusion.

https://play.golang.org/p/nXJoYLI758m

Comment: it should be just like this https://play.golang.org/p/Z1UTnLXwICV

Comment: missed a lost wg.Done call........ https://play.golang.org/p/4GshqCcd32m

Comment: Fixed (removed) an extra wg.Done() from printOutput().

Comment: yes, i did not read and tested my code sufficiently before posting. see https://play.golang.org/p/tqDK4kHbyfQ

Comment: @mh-cbon the second solution you submitted : 1. Does not execute in the playground, 2. The wg WaitGroup in the concurrent functions is not defined, and 3. Is actually pretty smart. The third solution is great

Comment: yes i am aware, i realized those problems trying it on the playground. So i gave you the fix, sorry for the noise and back and forth.